# Error al ejecutar gulp

Tags: javascript, json

[image: esta imagen muestra error al ejecutar gulp, después de actualizarlo e instalar módulos esto se presenta en un proyecto de JS-html-css con automatizado con gulp]

[image: aquí se encuentra el archivo del código de gulpfile]

## Este código es del archivo gulpfile.js

/*Este archivo es una copia de gulpfile para poder ejecutarlo hay que como código hay que crear la carpeta node_module y tener instalado gulp, node y python*/

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var webserver = require("gulp-webserver");
var opn = require("opn");
var phantom = require("gulp-phantom");
var casperJs = require("gulp-casperjs");

var csslint = require("gulp-csslint");
var jslint = require("gulp-jslint");

var server = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "8001",
};

gulp.task("webserver", function () {
  gulp.src("app").pipe(
    webserver({
      host: server.host,
      port: server.port,
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: false,
    })
  );
});

gulp.task("openbrowser", function () {
  opn("http://" + server.host + ":" + server.port);
});

gulp.task("watch", function () {
  gulp.watch("app/*.html");
  gulp.watch("app/css/*.css");
});

gulp.task("phantom", function () {
  gulp.src("./casper/*.js").pipe(phantom()).pipe(gulp.dest("./test_data/"));
});

gulp.task("casper", function () {
  gulp.src("./casper/*.js").pipe(casperJs());
});

gulp.task("validar-js", function () {
  gulp.src("app/script/*.js").pipe(jslint()).pipe(jslint.reporter("stylish"));
});

gulp.task("validar-css", function () {
  gulp
    .src("app/css/*.css")
    .pipe(csslint())
    .pipe(csslint.formatter(require("csslint-stylish")));
});

gulp.task("default", ["webserver", "watch", "openbrowser"]);
```

```js
{
  "name": "pruebas_automatizadas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "csslint-stylish": "0.0.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-casperjs": "0.0.6",
    "gulp-csslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-jslint": "^1.0.10",
    "gulp-phantom": "0.0.6",
    "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "phantomcss": "^1.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-csslint": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

***Error***

1. Este archivo es el la sección del gulpfile en las declaración de variables
2. Siempre me dice al ejecutar que el error esta en el opn y webserver pero no lo encuentro:

   var gulp = require("gulp");
   var webserver = require("gulp-webserver");
   var opn = require("opn");
   var phantom = require("gulp-phantom");
   var casperJs = require("gulp-casperjs");
   var csslint = require("gulp-csslint");
   var jslint = require("gulp-jslint");

[http://github.com/pluisfer](https://githubs.com/pluisfer)

Comment: Considera agregar el código y el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_ para mejor legibilidad, y modifica el título para que sea más descriptivo. Lee [ask].

Comment: ok, muchas gracias